# How to customize a offical docker postgres image and build it?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I need to change the locale of the offical `Postgres(11.4)` image in order to create databases with my language.

https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/87b15b6c65ba985ac958e7b35ba787422113066e/11/Dockerfile

I copied the `Dockerfile` and `docker-entrypoint.sh` from offical postgres image( I did not add the customization yet)

```
aek@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Docker$ ls
docker-entrypoint.sh  Dockerfile
aek@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Docker$ sudo docker build -t postgres_custom .

Step 24/24 : CMD ["postgres"]
 ---> Running in 8720b67094b1
Removing intermediate container 8720b67094b1
 ---> eb63a36ee850
Successfully built eb63a36ee850
Successfully tagged postgres_custom:latest
```

Image is successfully built but when I try to run it I get error below:

```
aek@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Docker$ docker run --name postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres_custom
d75b25367f019e3398f7daff78260e87c02a0c1898658585ec04bbd219bbe3e9
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"docker-entrypoint.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

Can't figure out what is wrong with the `entrypoint.sh`. Can you please help me?

Comment: please add your new Dockerfile to the question

Comment: I just copied Dockerfile and entrypoint.sh from the github offical postgres 11.4 which is https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/tree/87b15b6c65ba985ac958e7b35ba787422113066e/11. Did not add any customization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to make `entrypoint.sh` executable :

```
RUN chmod +x /path/to/entrypoint.sh
```

as you said that you copied it without any further changes.